# Retrieve values with the same equivalenceNo property with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a list of nodes `List<Node>` and a `Node` has a property `EnquivalenceNo`. What I'm trying to do is to retrieve the nodes with the same equivalence number but I haven't achieved that yet.

So my question is if there a way of getting the nodes with the same equivalence number using linq and putting the result of that query into another list?

For example:

List

```
 Node 1 { EquivalenceNo 1 }
 Node 2 { EquivalenceNo 2 }
 Node 3 { EquivalenceNo 2 }
 Node 4 { EquivalenceNo 8 }
```

The result should be something like this:

New List

```
 Node 2 { EquivalenceNo 2 }
 Node 3 { EquivalenceNo 2 }
```

Comment: Look at the `.Where()` LINQ method.

Comment: `So my question is if there a way of getting the nodes with the same equivalence number using linq and putting the result of that query into another list?` **YES**.  Another question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first  `GroupBy()`, than take only values  with more than 1 result and unwind wth `SelectMany`:

```
list.GroupBy(x => x.EquivalenceNo)
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I didn't downvote on your initial posting but I would think that the downvotes are because this answer is wrong.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't just delete and repost just to wash away the downvotes.

Comment: @MattRowland The topic starter thinks, it's the  right answer, down voting people, could explain, what's wrong  with the answer. Sure, it was not ok to delete answer and to post it again, but it was a help for somebody (topic starter)

Comment: Your solution will work in the test case that the OP showed. However, if there are multiple `Node`s with more than a `Count` of 1 then your solution will return all of those. "_getting the nodes with the same equivalence number_" is what was asked for, not finding `Node`s with multiple occurrences.